# Form doesn't send post

Tags: php, forms, post

Here is my form, it send POST to **loginuser.php** it have drop-down list which was read users from database.

```
<form action="loginuser.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="userList">
        <option> - - - </option>

        <?php
        include 'db.php';

        $sql = "SELECT username FROM dbusers";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option>" . $row["username"]. "</option>";
            }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name "password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Login</button>
</div>  
</form>
```

And this is my **loginuser.php** - when i push the Login button it send me to localhost/loginuser.php but it show "TEST-FALSE"

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
  echo "TEST - GOOD";

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `dbusers` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  }else{
    $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
  }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo "Succes";
}else{
  echo "TEST - FALSE";
}
?>
```

Also, my connection in db.php work because script on form show users correctly.

Comment: You didn't pass `username` you only passing `userlist`

Comment: `name "password"` is a typo, should have an `=`. So that won't be submitted. And your form does not contain a variable called "username" at all, only "userList"

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: And you should be hashing your passwords, not storing them as plain text.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It works.

Comment: No problem. The field names in the form have to match what the server is looking for - the computer cannot magically guess your intention. You should double-check this kind of basic thing before you start testing. And you should fix the SQL injection and other issues asap - a login form with basic security problems like this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes I know, but it works into intranet on LAN, now I just want to make connections step by step, then I will make security I think. Now it doesn't show "Succes" but only TEST-GOOD

Comment: I guess in that case that `if ($count == 1){` return false, then

Answer (score 0):

I changed some pass values in select drop down in your front end like and i dont know `name=password`  is typo error or not :

```
<form action="loginuser.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="userList">
        <option> - - - </option>

        <?php
        include 'db.php';

        $sql = "SELECT username FROM dbusers";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["username"]."'>" . $row["username"]. "</option>";
            }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Login</button>
</div>
```

and your php code is like:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['userList']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
  echo "TEST - GOOD";

  $username = $_POST['userList'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `dbusers` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  }else{
    $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
  }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo "Succes";
}else{
  echo "TEST - FALSE";
}
?>
```

Note: Please avoid the sql injection try to use PDO.,

Comment: then you need to check the query execution is correct or not and that is returning correct count @majsterfun

Answer (score -1):

You wrote this

```
<div class="form-group"> <input name "password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"> </div>
```

Correct with this

```
<div class="form-group"> <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"> </div>
```

name="password" (=) missing

Comment: correct but not the full story. More than this was already mentioned in the comments even before you answered.